# Printing program and function name of each instruction with Pin tool

Tags: c++, c++11, intel-pin

I'm new to writing a pin tool to instrument the program.
Currently, I'm kind of stuck with printing out the program name (image? I would say) and the function that the instruction belongs to.
For example, I I have a program foo.cpp and function name func() that simple addition and cout.
Then, when I use a pin tool, I want to print like below

0xAddress   foo (or lib64/ld-linux... etc)    func    disassembled_instruction (ex. move etc)

I can get the address and disassembled instructions, but not the program and function name.

Can anyone suggest me whether this is possible and how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Program Name**

To get the full path to the main binary (hence the program name) you must set an instrumentation routine for IMG (image) in your `main()` using [IMG_AddInstrumentFunction](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/group__IMG__BASIC__API.html#ga494869187b5d94d7dd346bc9ff49642f).

In the analysis callback (passed to `IMG_AddInstrumentFunction`) use the [IMG_IsMainExecutable](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/group__IMG__BASIC__API.html#gac8f52592ec23aa3eee464d3400f0ab51) function which simply returns a boolean indicating if the currently loaded image is the main binary (`true`) or not.

If the former function (`IMG_IsMainExecutable`) returns `true` you can call [IMG_Name](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/group__IMG__BASIC__API.html#ga50e1d947e0949aa33f0d35804968d560) to get its full path.

For a full example see the [Detecting the Loading and Unloading of Images (Image Instrumentation)](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/index.html#ImageLoad) example in the manual.

**Function Name**

Use [PIN_InitSymbols](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97554/Pin/html/group__PIN__CONTROL.html#ga8cf4aca0b0bdbc7fc0ae965883d8e3c2) in your main, before calling `PIN_StartProgram`.

You can instrument at the routine level using [RTN_AddInstrumentFunction](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/group__RTN__BASIC__API.html#gad10b9862dbe2f9bef8f7978492c35d01) (or get the routine from the instruction, BBL or TRACE).

Once you have the RTN (routine), you can get its name with the [RTN_Name](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/group__RTN__BASIC__API.html#gaf9d9689a59240ecc29c80d584f268c72) function.

Check the manual for the example [Procedure Instruction Count (Routine Instrumentation)](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/index.html#ProcInstrCount) which should give you a good start on how to use these functions.

Note: as obvious as its sounds, the target executable **must have** symbolic information (symbols): `No symbols == no routine names`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: @TJL Thanks! I completely forgot to add an explanation about the program name: more precisely how to get the path to the main executable. Done! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [standard predefined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) for printing out the program and function name.

`cout << __FILE__ << " " <<  __FUNCTION__ << endl;`

Comment: You are right! My question was kind of unclear on what I mean by the program name. I mean more of an image(?) that was loaded for that instruction (if I'm making sense). So, for example, pin tool also displays all the standard library images, so I would like to distinguish whether the instructions are only for the codes I wrote not the standard library calls or the compiler added during compilation time, etc. I'm sorry if it doesn't sound clear..